# Android NDK JNI shared variable is it possible?

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I would like to update progress of JNI method to Progress Bar. The simplest way I can think of without creating multiple worker threads would be to have shared variable in ProgressBar activity and then I would just update the shared variable in my JNI method if I get the correct pointer to the address. Is it possible? Or would I have to think of something else?

visible

```
static long int _PROGRESS = 0;
```

I would like to access this variable from native method call let's say

```
JNI_EXPORT java_com_example(env, jobject......){
for loop{
   //do something
  _PROGRESS++; }}
```

how can I best make a pointer to the shared variable? Or do I have to return everytime an update occurs, I would like to avoid this given JNI Call overheads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be a class static variable, as per the Java rules. There are no variables in global scope in Java.

To update one of those from the C side, use `JNIEnv::SetStaticLongField()`. To read the current value, use `GetStaticLongField()`. There's no direct variable access via JNI.

Note that `long int` is not a valid datatype in Java. `long` is. And it correponds to `jlong` on the C side, which is **not** the same as C `long`.

Comment: If that variable is accessed from multiple threads, it must be declared `volatile`, or synchronized.  The Dalvik JNI code will do the additional work required by the Java memory model.